# Audio is not playing after stop serviec in Media player

Tags: android, service, media-player

Guys I am working on Audio module in my app so i have created on simple Audio demo with service.

Its working up to `Play` - `Pause` - `Playing in Background` but issue is strange.

Simply while launch app i have added two Buttons like

- `Play/Pause` (Will change caption according state)
- `stop` (To stop service)

Now as i said my `play-pause & Stop` are working perfectly but when i try to play again audio after the click on `stop` its cause the problem in `Start`

`Error : 05-01 13:37:42.671: E/start(8096): java.lang.IllegalStateException`

- [Reference Link for Media Player State](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#Valid_and_Invalid_States)
- [Reference Link for play audio in background](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html)

**Audio_Activity.java**

```
public class Audio_Activity extends Activity {
  
    private static final String TAG = "ServicesDemo";
    public static Button play_pause;
    public static Button buttonStop;
    Audio_Service ms;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ms = new Audio_Service();
        play_pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play_pause);
        buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);

        play_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (isMyServiceRunning()) {
                        ms.play_pause();
                    } else {
                        startService(new Intent(Audio_Activity.this,
                                Audio_Service.class));
                        play_pause.setText("Pause");
                    }
                }
            });

        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (isMyServiceRunning()) {
                        ms.stop_audio();
                        stopService(new Intent(Audio_Activity.this,
                                Audio_Service.class));
                        play_pause.setText("Play");
                    } else {
                        stopService(new Intent(Audio_Activity.this,
                                Audio_Service.class));
                        play_pause.setText("Play");
                    }
                }

            });

    }

    public boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service: manager
            .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (Audio_Service.class.getName().equals(
                    service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Audio_Service.java**

```
public class Audio_Service extends Service implements OnErrorListener,
OnCompletionListener, OnPreparedListener {

    public static MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    Audio_Activity ac = new Audio_Activity();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        try {
            Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("ONdistroy", "" + e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        try {
            Log.e("player_status", "" + player);
            String url = "MY_WEB_URL";
            player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            player.reset();
            player.setDataSource(url);
            player.prepareAsync();
            player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            player.setOnErrorListener(this);
            player.setOnCompletionListener(this);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("start", "" + e);
        }
        // player.start();
    }

    public void play_pause() {
        try {
            if (player != null) {
                if (player.isPlaying()) {
                    ac.play_pause.setText("Play");
                    player.pause();
                } else {
                    ac.play_pause.setText("Pause");
                    player.start();

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("play_pause", "" + e);
        }
    }

    public void stop_audio() {
        try {
            if (player != null) {
                if (player.isPlaying()) {
                    ac.play_pause.setText("Play");
                    player.stop();
                    player.release();

                } else {
                    ac.play_pause.setText("Play");
                    player.release();

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("stop_service", "" + e);
        }
    }

    public void cleanUp() {

        if (player != null) {
            player.stop();
            player = null;
            player.release();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Log.d("complete", "called...........");

            player.stop();
            player.release();
            player = null;
            stopService(new Intent(this, Audio_Service.class));
            ac.play_pause.setText("Play");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("complete", "" + e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            player.stop();
            player.release();
            player = null;

            // mp.reset();
            ac.play_pause.setText("Play");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("onError", "" + e);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            player.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("onPrepare", "" + e);
        }
    }

}
```

I have added below things in `Manifest`file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<service 
 android:name=".Audio_Service" 
 android:enabled="true" />
```

**Update**

I know that i can play audio in ideal state for that i have to set `reset();` but don't know where.Because if i set in `onDestroy;` or `cleanUp()` or `stop_audio()` or `onStart()` then its adding one more error and that is `NullpointerException`.

Please guys help me. this error i am getting form last two days.
Correct me if i am wrong.

Tanks for take your time on my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use startService() to run your service and communicate with it using a Binder. It is not a regualr object, you need the Android OS to be made aware of it and you need to behave as it expects you to.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

You shouldn't create an instance yourself and shouldn't call its methods directly.

Comment: i have call my service `startService(new Intent(Audio_Activity.this,Audio_Service.class));` in `play_pause` click event

Comment: But you create an instance yourself using new and you communicatate with this instance using regular methods calls. This is not how a service is used. You need to let the OS create the instance itself after you call to startService(). You need to wait for a connection to the srevice to be established and you need to communicate with it using a Binder. See the link for more details.

Comment: thanks for link. its good. but i solved my issue, i have to add `player = null;` in `stop_audio()`.

Comment: That is a complex question. An Android service is not supposed to be used this way and I'm not intimately familiar with the Android's service code, so I do not know what the effects of using it this way will be.

Comment: ,okay. BTW right now my previous code is working and now i have also implement as per your link also.So i think that should be batter to follow because that is developers's link.Thanks for help me.

Answer (score 1):

i got solution after 5 min and i have done silly mistake.I was forgot to add `player = null;`

This whole code is working perfectly without any error but one of the developer (selalerer) also suggest me to [Refer this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). I have implement that way also and that is also working perfectly.

```
public void stop_audio() {
     try {
         if (player != null) {
             if (player.isPlaying()) {
                 ac.play_pause.setText("Play");
                 player.stop();
                 player.release();
                 player = null; // forgot this statement  

             } else {
                 ac.play_pause.setText("Play");
                 player.release();
                 player = null; // forgot this statement  

             }
         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         // TODO: handle exception
         Log.e("stop_service", "" + e);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you try stop after for play of audio

```
try {

    player.reset();
    player.setDataSource(url);
    player.prepare();
    player.seekTo(0);

} catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (SecurityException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
player.start();
```