# Mediaplayer track change issue

Tags: android

This is my code to play and update Track and on a button click I call the `update()` function but the track doesn't change properly.

First track plays just fine but when I try to switch to the next then it behaves improperly where am I wrong.

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
        mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        }

         public void prepareMediaPlayer(FileDescriptor fd)
         {
             try {
                 mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                 Log.d("player", "setAudiotStreamType");
                 mPlayer.setDataSource(fd); 
                 Log.d("player", "setDataSource");
                 mPlayer.prepareAsync();
                 Log.d("player", "prepareAsync");

             } 
             catch (IOException e) {}
             catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {} 
             catch (IllegalStateException e) {}
         }

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        }

        public void updateTrack()
        {
                        File f=(File) imageFilexxSm.values().toArray()[index];
                    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
                    prepareMediaPlayer(inputStream.getFD());
                    inputStream.close();

                    if(mPlayer.isPlaying())
                    {   
                    mPlayer.stop();
                    mPlayer.reset();
                    mPlayer.reset();
                    }

                    else
                    {
                    mPlayer.start();    
                    }   

        }
```

Log:

```
05-11 13:17:42.782: E/MediaPlayer(14969): start called in state 4
05-11 13:17:42.782: E/MediaPlayer(14969): error (-38, 0)
05-11 13:17:42.821: I/dalvikvm-heap(14969): Grow heap (frag case) to 34.372MB for 4194320-byte allocation
05-11 13:17:43.040: I/System.out(14969): index value is 0/1024/0
05-11 13:17:43.087: I/dalvikvm-heap(14969): Grow heap (frag case) to 30.457MB for 2261008-byte allocation
05-11 13:17:43.189: E/MediaPlayer(14969): attachNewPlayer called in state 8
05-11 13:17:43.220: I/Choreographer(14969): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-11 13:17:43.275: I/dalvikvm-heap(14969): Grow heap (frag case) to 34.452MB for 4194320-byte allocation
05-11 13:17:43.392: I/MediaPlayer(14969): Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
05-11 13:17:43.392: E/MediaPlayer(14969): Error (-38,0)
05-11 13:17:57.642: I/System.out(14969): action down
05-11 13:17:57.642: I/System.out(14969): points 1.6014493?21
05-11 13:17:57.642: I/System.out(14969): show one page
05-11 13:17:57.642: I/System.out(14969): start curl right
05-11 13:17:57.650: I/System.out(14969): index value is 1/1024/1
05-11 13:17:57.681: I/dalvikvm-heap(14969): Grow heap (frag case) to 30.401MB for 2261008-byte allocation
05-11 13:17:57.775: E/MediaPlayer(14969): attachNewPlayer called in state 128
05-11 13:17:57.821: I/dalvikvm-heap(14969): Grow heap (frag case) to 34.401MB for 4194320-byte allocation
05-11 13:18:04.704: I/System.out(14969): action down
05-11 13:18:04.704: I/System.out(14969): points 1.692029?21
05-11 13:18:04.704: I/System.out(14969): show one page
05-11 13:18:04.704: I/System.out(14969): start curl right
05-11 13:18:04.704: I/System.out(14969): index value is 2/1024/2
05-11 13:18:04.736: I/dalvikvm-heap(14969): Grow heap (frag case) to 30.315MB for 2261008-byte allocation
05-11 13:18:04.829: E/MediaPlayer(14969): attachNewPlayer called in state 128
05-11 13:18:04.876: I/dalvikvm-heap(14969): Grow heap (frag case) to 34.316MB for 4194320-byte allocation
05-11 13:18:08.845: I/System.out(14969): action down
05-11 13:18:08.845: I/System.out(14969): points 1.5471015?21
05-11 13:18:08.845: I/System.out(14969): show one page
05-11 13:18:08.845: I/System.out(14969): start curl right
05-11 13:18:08.845: I/System.out(14969): index value is 3/1024/3
05-11 13:18:08.876: I/dalvikvm-heap(14969): Grow heap (frag case) to 30.316MB for 2261008-byte allocation
05-11 13:18:08.970: E/MediaPlayer(14969): attachNewPlayer called in state 16
05-11 13:18:09.025: I/dalvikvm-heap(14969): Grow heap (frag case) to 34.316MB for 4194320-byte allocation
05-11 13:18:12.892: I/System.out(14969): action down
05-11 13:18:12.892: I/System.out(14969): points 1.5688405?21
05-11 13:18:12.892: I/System.out(14969): show one page
05-11 13:18:12.892: I/System.out(14969): start curl right
05-11 13:18:12.892: I/System.out(14969): index value is 4/1024/4
05-11 13:18:12.923: I/dalvikvm-heap(14969): Grow heap (frag case) to 30.316MB for 2261008-byte allocation
05-11 13:18:13.025: E/MediaPlayer(14969): start called in state 4
05-11 13:18:13.025: E/MediaPlayer(14969): error (-38, 0)
05-11 13:18:13.064: I/dalvikvm-heap(14969): Grow heap (frag case) to 34.316MB for 4194320-byte allocation
05-11 13:18:13.126: E/MediaPlayer(14969): Error (-38,0)
05-11 13:18:13.126: I/MediaPlayer(14969): Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
05-11 13:18:18.228: I/System.out(14969): action down
05-11 13:18:18.236: I/System.out(14969): points -1.5289855?21
05-11 13:18:18.236: I/System.out(14969): show one page
05-11 13:18:18.236: I/System.out(14969): index value is 3/1024/3
05-11 13:18:18.259: I/dalvikvm-heap(14969): Grow heap (frag case) to 30.316MB for 2261008-byte allocation
05-11 13:18:18.353: E/MediaPlayer(14969): attachNewPlayer called in state 8
05-11 13:18:18.400: I/dalvikvm-heap(14969): Grow heap (frag case) to 34.316MB for 4194320-byte allocation
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315043/audio-is-not-playing-after-stop-serviec-in-media-player

Comment: @chintankhetiya I couldn't find the right solution that's why I have posted my thread can you just help me with this.

Comment: given links is perfect you can go with it, even i have post my answer also. check it out. its working .

Comment: @chintankhetiya Actualy as you may see that I have got File objects where I have stored my mp3 files and now I am trying to play them. How would your code help in my use case. Would that be right to use it.

Comment: that doesn't matter that from where you calling your mp3 file , it could be live streaming or form local path , rest of the code is same for maintaining states, just go through and adjust as per your needs

Comment: @chintankhetiya Is this the whole code in your question or do I need any changes for just audio playback.

Comment: listen, that will play audio from live stream and play in background also, even if you exit form app. so if you want to play in background then go with same and just update your local file url otherwise remove service code and maintain your state

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things stick out:

1. You're using `prepareAsync`, which is *asynchronous*. That is, you should wait for the `onPrepared` callback before you do anything that relies on the preparation to be complete (like calling `start`). That's why you get the "`start called in state 4`" error message (state 4 is `MEDIA_PLAYER_PREPARING`).
2. If `updateTrack` is called during ongoing playback it doesn't seem like you stop the `MediaPlayer` before preparing it for a new song. You've got a call to `stop` *after* the call to `prepareMediaPlayer` but that won't do you much good. To be able to re-prepare the player you have to `stop` it first, and if you also want to change the data source you'll have to `reset` the player after stopping it.

Refer to the [MediaPlayer documentation's state diagram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram) for the set of valid state transitions.

Comment: I basically have a set of file objects i.e. filedescriptor inputstreams as you may see in the above code. How and where can it be edited, as I know it that the `FileDescriptor` inputstream gets changed but the issue is only with media player.

Comment: That seems less important. It's safe to close the FileInputStream after `setDataSource` returns. The important thing is to make sure that the `MediaPlayer` object is in the correct state; i.e. make sure that `prepareAsync` has finished before you call `start`, and make sure that you `stop` it before doing another `prepareAsync`.

Comment: And how would I come to know if prepareAsyc has finished?

Comment: By using the [OnPreparedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.html), which is your (currently empty) `onPrepared` method.

Comment: What is the right method to know if the mediaplayer is prepared and now I should start, shall I do it like this :- `public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
  if(arg0.isPlaying())
  {
  mPlayer.start(); 
  }
 }`

Comment: When `onPrepared` is called, the player will be in PREPARED state. Therefore you shouldn't call `isPlaying`, you can just call `start`. As for the `attachNewPlayer` error, that's most likely because you call `setDataSource` on your recycled player object without having called `reset` first.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29770/discussion-between-pks-and-michael)